# What is the shortcut to minimize all the windows except the active one in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, debian-wheezy, aero-snap

I know there's 'Aero Shake' for Windows and I want something similar for Debian 7.

I already checked all the keyboard shortcuts but couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Which Desktop do you use?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/40022/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-minimizing-all-windows-except-the-active-one whether this helps.

Comment: @davidbaumann - Debian 7.0

Comment: This is your distribution, not the desktop (gnome, kde....)

Comment: @davidbaumann - Oh sorry. It's GNOME 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works in Ubuntu is:

Ctrl + Super + Up: Maximize

Ctrl + Super + Down: Restore/Minimize

Ctrl + Super + Left: Snap window left

Ctrl + Super + Right: Snap window right

And if you hold down the Super key, you can get a list of these, and other, keyboard shortcuts.

PS. Super key aka windows key in

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut to do this, but I believe it's possible using Devil's Pie.

Here's a useful article with a basic example.
http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~gwiener/linux/minimizing-all-windows-in-gnome/

See "window_property" here: 
http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie#window_role

See "_NET_WM_STATE" on this page. You're specifically looking for "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED".
http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472615568

I don't have a test environment ATM, but I believe the script would look something like:

```
(begin
  (if (not (is (window_property _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED))
    (minimize))
 (quit))
```

or (See the section on _NET_WM_STATE... Not sure how to use these)

```
(begin
  (if (not (is (window_property _NET_WM_STATE, ATOM))
    (minimize))
 (quit))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with on Ubuntu 21.10 that implments Wayland by default. Bind the bash script to a key and you are ready to go.

```
#!/bin/bash
gdbus call \
  --session \
  --dest org.gnome.Shell \
  --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
  --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
  "global
      .get_window_actors()
      .filter(w=>w.meta_window.has_focus()===false)
      .forEach(w=>w.meta_window.minimize())"
```